# Как вывести видео на сайте, зная его имя?

Tags: php

Сделал добавление видео на сайт, файлы загружаются в ту папку, которую я указал. В базу данных я заношу имя файла, размер, тип. Как мне вывести мои видео в нужно место?
Я попробовал в базу данных добавить ещё одно поле. Поле с директорией видео и поэтому столбцу вывести. На странице пусто, но через консоль видно 3 видео.
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

```
                    <?
                        // Если количество записей больше нуля
                        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
                        {
                        // Записываем полученные данные в массив
                        $myrow = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
                        // В цикле выводи видео на страницу
                        do {
                        echo "<video><source src='admin_panel/".$myrow['catalog'].$myrow['file']."' type='video/mp4'  /></video>";
                            } 
                        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
                            }
                            else
                                    {
                                        // Собщение о пустой таблице
                                        echo "<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена, в таблице нет записей.</p>";
                                        exit();
                                    }
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Помогло изменение `$myrow['catalog'].'/'.$myrow['file']`. Но видео вывелись, как картинки. Добавил к тегу video атрибуты `controls` и всё заработало :)